# C# Save file dialog box error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I created a simple project for parking car. When i register any user and save it in access database.After saving Dialog box is shown and ask me to save that user but problem when Dialog Box is shown error comes out about access violation exception.Read or write protected memory i don't know how to fix.
I read some blogs and posts about this error but no provide a correct solution and also not post any correct idea. 
Below is my complete code how can i fix.

```
            using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.Configuration;
        using System.Data.OleDb;
        using MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec;
        using MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.Data;
        using System.IO;
        using NPR.Properties;

        namespace NPR
        {
        public partial class UserAdd : Form
        {
        public UserAdd()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }
        private int userId = 0;
        public int UserId
        {
        get { return userId; }
        set { userId = value; }
        }

        private bool isUpdate = false;
        public bool IsUpdate
        {
        get { return isUpdate; }
        set { isUpdate = value; }

        }

        private void UpdateRecord()
        {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
        string cmdString = "Update users SET u_name = @name,u_car_no = @car_no, u_mobile_no = @mobile_no,u_license_no = @license_no,u_reg_date = @reg_date , u_image=@firstimage,u_car_background=@secondimage WHERE Id = @userId";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, con))
        {
        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", NameTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car_no", PlateNoTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile_no", MobileTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@license_no", LicenseTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg_date", DateTime.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstimage", savePhoto());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondimage", savePhoto2());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", this.userId);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        }
        }

        private void SaveRecord()
        {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
        string cmdString = "INSERT INTO users (u_name,u_car_no,u_mobile_no,u_license_no,u_reg_date,u_image,u_car_background) VALUES (@name,@car_no,@mobile_no,@license_no,@reg_date,@firstimage,@secondimage)";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, con))
        {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", NameTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car_no", PlateNoTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile_no", MobileTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@license_no", LicenseTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg_date", DateTime.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstimage", savePhoto());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondimage", savePhoto2());

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        }
        }

        private byte[] savePhoto()
        {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        FirstpictureBox.Image.Save(ms, FirstpictureBox.Image.RawFormat);
        return ms.GetBuffer();
        }
        private byte[] savePhoto2()
        {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        SecondpictureBox.Image.Save(ms, SecondpictureBox.Image.RawFormat);
        return ms.GetBuffer();
        }

        private bool IsValidated()
        {
        if (NameTextBox.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Name is Required.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        NameTextBox.Focus();
        return false;
        }
        if (PlateNoTextBox.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Car Plate No. is Required.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        PlateNoTextBox.Focus();
        return false;
        }
        if (MobileTextBox.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Mobile No. is Required.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        MobileTextBox.Focus();
        return false;
        }
        if (LicenseTextBox.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("License No. is Required.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        NameTextBox.Focus();
        return false;
        }
        if (DateTime.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Date is Required.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        DateTime.Focus();
        return false;
        }
        return true;

        }

        private DataTable GetUserInfoById()
        {
        DataTable dtUsersInfo = new DataTable();
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
        string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = @UserId";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, con))
        {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", this.UserId);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dtUsersInfo.Load(reader);
        }
        }

        return dtUsersInfo;
        }

        private Image LoadImg(byte[] img)
        {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
        return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        this.Close();
        }

        private void SecondpictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Select Car Background Image";
        ofd.Filter = "Image File(*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
        SecondpictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
        }
        }

        private void FirstpictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Select User Profile Image";
        ofd.Filter = "Image File(*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
        FirstpictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
        }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        DataTable dtUsers = GetUserInfoById();
        DataRow row = dtUsers.Rows[0];
        PlateNoTextBox.Text = row["u_car_no"].ToString();

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
        string cmdString = "DELETE * FROM users WHERE Id = @UserId";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, con))
        {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", this.UserId);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        }
        string connString2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
        string camdString = "Update slots SET u_name = @name,u_car_no = @car_no,Status = 0 WHERE u_car_no = @slotId";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString2))
        {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(camdString, conn))
        {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", " ");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car_no", " ");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slotId", row["u_car_no"]);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("User Deleted Successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        this.Close();
        }

        private void viewDataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        this.Hide();
        AllUserDetail mef = new AllUserDetail();
        mef.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        this.Hide();
        Dashboard dsh = new Dashboard();
        dsh.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void UserAdd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (this.IsUpdate)
        {
        DataTable dtUsers = GetUserInfoById();
        DataRow row = dtUsers.Rows[0];
        NameTextBox.Text = row["u_name"].ToString();
        PlateNoTextBox.Text = row["u_car_no"].ToString();
        MobileTextBox.Text = row["u_mobile_no"].ToString();
        LicenseTextBox.Text = row["u_license_no"].ToString();
        DateTime.Text = row["u_reg_date"].ToString();
        FirstpictureBox.Image = (row["u_image"] is DBNull) ? Resources.no_thumb : LoadImg((byte[])row["u_image"]);
        SecondpictureBox.Image = (row["u_car_background"] is DBNull) ? Resources.no_thumb : LoadImg((byte[])row["u_car_background"]);
        }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (IsValidated())
        {
        try
        {
        if (this.isUpdate)
        {
        UpdateRecord();
        String plate = PlateNoTextBox.Text;
        QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
        Bitmap qrcode = encoder.Encode(plate);
        qrimage.Image = qrcode as Image;
        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
        s.Title = "Save QR Code";
        s.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg|PNG|*.png|BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif";
        if (s.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
        try
        {
        qrimage.Image.Save(s.FileName);
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" + ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
        }
        }
        else
        {
        SaveRecord();
        String plate = PlateNoTextBox.Text;
        QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
        Bitmap qrcode = encoder.Encode(plate);
        qrimage.Image = qrcode as Image;
        MessageBox.Show("Record Save Successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
        s.Title = "Save QR Code";
        s.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg|PNG|*.png|BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif";

        if (s.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
        try
        {
        qrimage.Image.Save(s.FileName);
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" + ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        }
        }
        this.Close();
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" + ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
```

Problem i face it in `SaveRecord();` function dialog box.

```
if (s.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)   //Here is error
        {
        try
        {
        qrimage.Image.Save(s.FileName);
        }
```

Comment: the place you are saving the file do have file write permission ?

Comment: PLEASE do not dump your code asking someone else to debug your code! Write a small example to reproduce it!!!

Comment: My project in local disk d and always permission to save file here

Comment: Adrino i was posted because anyone who know about this exception will tell me about my mistake easily.

Comment: @user5832488 AcessViolationException, as you can imagine, is about something weird with pointers (or with interop to native code). Anyone who _knows about this exception_ cannot help you unless browse all your code to find a silly mistake or start a debugging session (things that you should do first together with a MCVE when posting)

Answer (score -1):

Please try to add `s.InitialDirectory = "D:\\";` to prevent access to special directories when dialog opens